# Redirecting to a new page when a user is using Internet Explorer

Tags: php, html

I am using the code below in order to redirect the users who use Internet Explorer to a new page, but obviously there is something wrong with the code, since the site doesn't load anymore when I am using Internet Explorer.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== FALSE) {
    $url = htmlspecialchars($_GET['url']);
    header( 'Location: http://'.$url.'' ) ;
    }
    ?>
```

Since I don't know what I am doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated if someone could post the right way to do it with the right coding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: url contains an address of the form www.mysite.com/main.html and I do not really know the right way to do it :)

Comment: its poor practice to write browser specific code theses days, and no way will work 100%

Comment: Try this , check this answer , [Click Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150335/how-can-i-use-php-to-redirect-ie-users-to-a-certain-page/11150358#11150358

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get_browser()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php#101125) to get the user browser and then use the if condition.

You can try this:

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
if($browser['browser'] == "Internet Explorer"){
    $url = htmlspecialchars($_GET['url']);
    header( 'Location: http://'.$url.'' );
} else {
    // do something...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== FALSE)

!== typo ? It should be something like

strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') == TRUE)

Comment: no, that should be correct. Checks for equality AND same type.

Comment: Thanks I was unaware of that.

Comment: R. nope, it's the same thing as `=== TRUE`

Answer (score -1):

For modern IE you can use:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Trident') !== false) {
    header('Location: ie-page.php');
    exit;
} else {
    print "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: This works for all versions of IE. Why was this down voted?