# How can I use PHP to redirect IE users to a certain page?

Tags: php, internet-explorer, redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Redirecting to a new page when a user is using Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911107/redirecting-to-a-new-page-when-a-user-is-using-internet-explorer)

I'm working on a version of my website which renders properly in Internet Explorer; what would a PHP script, which automatically redirects users with an IE user agent to (for example) /index-ie.php, look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

PHP have function **$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']** used to identify browser

```
 if(using_ie())
 {
   //redirect
 }
function using_ie() 
    { 
        $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
        $ub = False; 
        if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent)) 
        { 
            $ub = True; 
        } 

        return $ub; 
    }
```

Comment: It's a variable, not a function. Besides that, this will also catch e.g. Opera browsers which are configured to use an IE useragent.

Comment: Actually, if you are talking about $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] it's an array. This statement retrieves the value stored in that location within the array.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function to search the string for `MSIE`. ex,

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false) {
  header('Location: /index-ie.php');
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all information about user browser --

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
function using_ie()
{
    $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $ub = False;
    if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $ub = True;
    }

    return $ub;
}
```

You will get value 1 if it is internet explorer.

Answer (score -2):

Hope this works:

```
     $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

     if(preg_match('MSIE',$user_agent))
     {
       header('Location: https://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/index.php']);
     }
```